# Let R be the equivalence relation on Z defined by xRy if x^2 ≡ y^2 (mod 5). Give a partition on Z with respect to R.

Tags: logic, modular-forms

Let R be the equivalence relation on Z defined by xRy if x^2 ≡ y^2(mod 5). Give a partition
on Z with respect to R.

(Hint: You may use the following results: For any x ∈ Z,
x^2 ≡ 0 (mod 5) if and only if x ≡ 0 (mod 5),
x^2 ≡ 1 (mod 5) if and only if x ≡ 1 (mod 5) or x ≡ 4 (mod 5),
x^2 ≡ 4 (mod 5) if and only if x ≡ 2 (mod 5) or x ≡ 3 (mod 5). )

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: That hint isn't a hint, it's basically a solution.